# Calcular el total anual para el año anterior en PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax

¿Cómo puedo calcular la suma **total anual de una medida para el año anterior al actual**? En concreto, necesito calcular el total de ventas del año pasado. De esta forma, si a esto le sumo otra medida con las ventas del año actual (y voy filtrando por meses) conseguiré el acumulado del año pasado y lo que va de éste.

Esto es lo que tengo hasta ahora:

```
    total_sales =
    VAR sales_last_year =
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(fact_sale_order[sales_amount]),
        DATEADD(dim_date[formatted_date], -1, YEAR)
    )

    VAR sales_current_year =
    SUM(fact_sale_order[sales_amount])

    RETURN sales_last_year + sales_current_year
```

Sin embargo si, por ejemplo, **filtro por el mes de Enero**, en sales_last_year **no obtendré las ventas de todo el año**, sino que tan solo tendré las de enero de 2021. El resultado que busco es el total del año anterior.

Por si no me he explicado bien, os pongo **un ejemplo** de lo que quiero:

- Ventas totales en **2021**: $ 20,000
- Ventas en enero de 2022: $ 3,000
- Ventas en febrero de 2022: $ 2,000.

El resultado que busco es:

- **Cuando filtro con un slicer para enero y para 2022**, el resultado
  de mi expresión debería ser $ 23,000.
- **Cuando filtro con un slicer de datos para febrero y 2022**, el resultado de mi expresión debería ser $ 25,000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solución:

```html
total_sales = 
VAR last_year = YEAR(MAX(dim_date[formatted_date]))-1

VAR sales_last_year =
    CALCULATE(
        SUM(fact_sale_order[sales_amount]),
        FILTER(ALLEXCEPT(dim_date, dim_date[year]), YEAR(dim_date[formatted_date]) = last_year )
    )

VAR sales_current_year =
CALCULATE(
    SUM(fact_sale_order[sales_amount]),
    DATESYTD(dim_date[formatted_date])
)
RETURN sales_last_year + sales_current_year
```

Comment: Pulsa en [edit] y describe qué hace tu código. Puede que para ti sea obvio, pero para otros, no. Lee [answer]. Además, recuerda que el formato del sitio es de _preguntas y respuestas_, no de un foro. No coloques "resuelto" o similares en la pregunta, solo acepta la respuesta que te ha sido más útil.

Answer (score 0):

Entiendo que quieres sumar el total del año anterior con lo que llevas de año actual según el filtro aplicado.

Pureba algo así, lo hago de memoria

```
total_sales =
VAR Anyo_anterior = YEAR(TODAY())

VAR sales_last_year =
CALCULATE(
    SUM(fact_sale_order[sales_amount]),
    ALL(dim_date),
    FILTER(dim_date, YEAR(dim_date[formatted_date]) = Anyo_anterior )
)

VAR sales_current_year =
CALCULATE(
    SUM(fact_sale_order[sales_amount]),
    ALL(dim_date),
    FILTER(dim_date, YEAR(dim_date[formatted_date]) = YEAR(TODAY()),
    FILTER(dim_date, dim_date[formatted_date] <= SELECTEDVALUE(dim_date[formatted_date]))
)

RETURN sales_last_year + sales_current_year
```

La función `ALL()` elimina el filtro aplicado, en este caso el de fechas (tabla dim_date)

Comment: Muchas gracias! Efectivamente, eso es lo que quiero. Sin embargo, hay un problema: si, por ejemplo, filtro por marzo, me suma el resultado del año anterior y el resultado de marzo (sin contar enero y febrero). ¿Cómo podría hacer para que me sumase también los meses de enero y febrero? Muchas gracias, Roger

Comment: @CLT A ver si ahora te funciona. El cálculo del año actual sigue un patrón parecido. Le decimos que tome los datos del año actual y filtramos por un valor de la fecha seleccionada (o mes) o anterior.